# what does index .Values() mean in helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

what does **index .Values (printf "%sHost" .Chart.Name)** return?

Below is snippet of code from a .tpl file

{{- define "mediawiki.host" -}}

{{- $host := **index .Values (printf "%sHost" .Chart.Name)** | default "" -}}

{{- default (include "mediawiki.serviceIP" .) $host -}}

{{- end -}}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

About index function from [go template docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template)

> index
>
> Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the
> following arguments. Thus "index x 1 2 3" is, in Go syntax,
> x[1][2][3]. Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array.

If a chart name is "mediawiki" (it is by default) then the function returns value of the [`.Values.mediawikiHost`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mediawiki/values.yaml#L99) key

```
.Chart.Name == "mediawiki"
printf "%sHost" .Chart.Name == "mediawikiHost"
index .Values "mediawikiHost" == ""
```